# In a java class how/when does code in brackets get executed?

Tags: java, class

So I was looking at this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850469/creating-an-array-in-a-class/7850491#7850491).  And people were suggesting that you can put code in a java class like so

```
class myClass
{
  int a;

  {
    //insert code here dealing with a
  }
}
```

How does the code in the brackets get executed and when does it get executed?  Is there any limit to what I can put there or is it just reserved for variable initialization?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Some questions regarding Initialization Block in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703215/some-questions-regarding-initialization-block-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class X

    Foo x = something;  // a variable initializer

    // an instance initializer
    { 
        statement1 
    }

    ...

    X()
    {
        statement2
    }
```

the constructor is translated to

```
    X()
    {
        super();

        // instance initializers and variable initializers
        // in their textual order
        x = something;
        statement1    
        ...

        // the original constructor body
        statement2
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an instance initialization block. I would recommend [reading this article](http://www.artima.com/designtechniques/initializationP.html). It is called before any constructor in the current class is executed and after all super-class constructors have completed.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a simple test to check the order of execution of different blocks:

```
class MyClass {
        MyClass() {
                System.out.println("construtor");
        }

        static {
                System.out.println("static block");
        }

        {
                System.out.println("initialization block");
        }
}
```

Result:

```
static block
initialization block
construtor
```

Answer (score 1):

This code block is executed per instance i.e. it has access to instance methods, fields etc.

It is executed after the constructor hierarchy of that class has been executed but before that class' constructor.

Thus you have to be careful what data you access in there.

Example:

```
class Foo {
  protected String name;

  {
    System.out.println("Foo's name: " + name);  
  } 

  public Foo(String n) {
    name = n; 
    System.out.println("constructing Foo");
  }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  {
    System.out.println("Bar's name: " + name); 
  }

  public Bar(String n) {
    super(n); 
    System.out.println("constructing Bar");
  }
}
```

If you now create a new `Bar` instance using `new Bar("baz");`, you would see this output:

```
Foo's name: null
constructing Foo
Bar's name: baz
constructing Bar
```

As you can see, the execution order of this is:

1. `Foo` initializer block
2. `Foo` constructor
3. `Bar` initializer block
4. `Bar` constructor